# how to get http status code with netcat via bash script

Tags: linux, bash, http, centos, netcat

I have to write a bash script that has to include these conditions. I am newbee can you give me an advise please?

This script runs with "command and [parameter]".
I give it to domain as a variable and script has to get this variable's status code with **"nc"** (I have not use cURL). If the status code is 200 (only), bash script print OK, otherwise script should exit with status code 7 without any prints words on screen.

I wrote this but when I use variables I am not able to get any result.

1-) this works (this is without variable, I know google responses 301 so I wrote grep 301)

```
#!/bin/bash

        STATUS=`printf 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n' | nc google.com 80 | awk '{print $2}' | grep '301'`
                if [ "$STATUS" -eq 301  ]; then
                echo "OK"
                else
                exit 7
                fi
```

2-) this is not work - please help me improve this script. I have to write with nc command to get response code and compare with 200.

```
#!/bin/bash

DOMAIN=google.com

        STATUS=`printf 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: "$DOMAIN"\r\n\r\n' | nc "$DOMAIN" 80 | awk '{print $2}' | grep '301'`
                if [ "$STATUS" ]; then
                        echo "OK"
                else
                        exit 7
                fi
```

Comment: Why `nc`? What's wrong with `curl`?

Comment: I can write with curl but they force me to do with nc. It's a task so I have to find a way to solve this problem with netcat.

Comment: Okay I got it, thanks. Good luck!

Comment: I suggest to switch from `GET` to [`HEAD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods).

Comment: Without `nc`, `curl` or `wget`: `exec 3<>/dev/tcp/www.google.com/80; echo -e 'HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n' >&3; cat <&3 | while read -r foo status foo; do echo "$status"; break; done`

Answer (score 0):

If have put together a small script. Hope that helps. PLEASE test before your production use :)

```
STATUS=$(printf "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: nc/0.0.1\r\nHost: $1\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n" | nc $1 80 | sed -n 's/HTTP.* \(.*\) .*/\1/p' |grep $2)

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo OK
else
  exit 7
fi
```

Your `print` command will work likewise:

```
STATUS=$(printf "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: nc/0.0.1\r\nHost: $1\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n" | nc $1 80 | awk '{print $2}' |grep $2)
```

The grep in the way you are using it will print 200. That means we have to check in the if block against an actual value.

I am checking the last exit code. If the grep command was successful - means it has found 200 in the HTTP response code - the exit code will be 0.

I am issuing the script like `./demo.sh nginx.org 200`